# vmap for find-and-replace in a visually selected block

Tags: vim

I can use this statement to change all `"`s to a `'` in a visually selected block in vim: `:'<,'>s/\%V"/'/g`.

How can I create a mapping to make this a little easier to type?

Answer (score 0):

With some experimentation I came up with: `vmap <leader>r :s/\%V`